# ComboBox no actualiza sus items al ejecutar esta acción con un Button en C#

Tags: c#, botón, combobox, binding

Intento hacer un programa en C# en el que un ComboBox actualiza sus items cada que le doy click a un Button con el string "Persona " + un numero aleatorio, el ComboBox esta enlazado con la lista ListaCambios. Mi problema es que cuando le doy click al Button la primera vez, los items se cargan de manera perfecta, pero, al dar click por segunda vez los items del ComboBox no se actualizan, esto fue lo que hice

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<ClaseCambio> ListaCambios = new List<ClaseCambio>();
        Random? random;    

        public class ClaseCambio
        {
            public string? Cambios { get; set;}
        }


        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListaCambios.Clear();
            random= new Random();
            int aleatorio = random.Next(0, 10);
            ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 1).ToString() });
            ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 2).ToString() });
            ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 3).ToString() });
       
            cbxCambios.ItemsSource= ListaCambios;
            MessageBox.Show("Intento " + (1 + aleatorio).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Y el XAML es :

```
<Window x:Class="Pruebacbx.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pruebacbx"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="472,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" Height="38" Name="cbxCambios">

            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cambios}"></TextBlock>
                        
                    </StackPanel>
                    
                </DataTemplate>
                
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,129,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="2.891,2.626" Height="61" Width="105" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Alguien sabe que pueda estar mal en mi codigo que me impida actualizar los items del ComboBox cada que le doy click al Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Porque `List` no implementa ningún mecanismo que alerte al componente (combobox en este caso) que ha sufrido una modificación.

La solución simple es usar un tipo de colección que implemente este mecanismo, .net ya cuenta con varias colecciones de ese tipo como por ejemplo `ObservableCollection`. Además no es necesario hacer esto `cbxCambios.ItemsSource = ListaCambios;` cada vez que haces click, el datasource se setea una sola vez.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //cambiamos List por ObservableCollection
    ObservableCollection<ClaseCambio> ListaCambios = new ObservableCollection<ClaseCambio>();
        
    Random? random;

    public class ClaseCambio
    {
        public string? Cambios { get; set; }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //el itemsource lo seteamos al inicio 
        cbxCambios.ItemsSource = ListaCambios;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            
        ListaCambios.Clear();
        random = new Random();
        int aleatorio = random.Next(0, 10);
        ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 1).ToString() });
        ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 2).ToString() });
        ListaCambios.Add(new ClaseCambio { Cambios = "Persona " + (aleatorio + 3).ToString() });
        MessageBox.Show("Intento " + (1 + aleatorio).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: otro truco menos correcto es reasignarlo haciendo `cbxCambios.Itemsource=null;cbxCambios.itemsource=ListaCambios;`

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfecto